# Zend 2 time filter in route validators

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've used a datetime filter earlier but now I need only a time filter.
My datetime filter is below

```
api\Rest\Activity\\Validator' => array(

    0=> array(
                    'name' => 'DateTimeTo',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'name' => 'Zend\\Filter\\DateTimeFormatter',
                            'options' => array(
                                'format' => 'Y-m-d',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(),
                    'allow_empty' => true,
                    'continue_if_empty' => true,
                    'error_message' => 'Invalid DateTimeTo, Please enter a valid Input in dd/mm/yyyy format.',
                ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found the Solution No Need for seprate filter just change the format of datetime (Y-m-d) to (h:i:s) thats it.

```
api\Rest\Activity\\Validator' => array(

    0=> array(
                    'name' => 'DateTimeTo',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters' => array(
                        0 => array(
                            'name' => 'Zend\\Filter\\DateTimeFormatter',
                            'options' => array(
                                'format' => 'h:i:s',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(),
                    'allow_empty' => true,
                    'continue_if_empty' => true,
                    'error_message' => 'Invalid DateTimeTo, Please enter a valid Input in dd/mm/yyyy format.',
                ),
    )
```